# How do I use flex direction in ordered list in NavBar with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox

Hi I am building a NavBar in ReactJs without any UI library like bootstrap or material just CSS and I want to use flex-direction: row in ol but its not working.
You can see my code below for NavBar component.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './landingnav.css';


export default class LandingNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navcontainer">
      <div className="navbarlogo">
        <h3>Codolas</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="navitems">
            <ol className="leftlist">
                <li>Why Codolas?</li>
                <li>Solutions</li>
                <li>About us</li>
                </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is CSS for the same component

```
.navcontainer {
    background-color: rgb(97, 252, 162);
    height: 84px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -18px;
}

.navbarlogo h3 {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0px;
}

.leftlist {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: My only bet is that the styles might not be imported due to the right path. Check that first

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the list items a flex: 1, the children don't know how much to flex across the space.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the issue actually after adding position: relative to navcontainer, I just simply added ol and put the styles of flex in it and it worked. Thanks to all. Happy coding